# angular 2 - primeng add button next to tabs

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

so I have requirement to have two tabs and a button , i am new to primeng and have created the tabs component, which works fine, see code below, but i am not able to create a button in the same row.

```
<p-tabView class="info-audit-tabview">
    <div class="ui-tabview-panels">
        <p-tabPanel header="UnSelected List">


        </p-tabPanel>

        <p-tabPanel header="Selected List" ng-reflect-header="Audit Trail">
        </p-tabPanel>
    </div>
</p-tabView>
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like a `new tab` button in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap classes, add col-md-4 or col-md-6 for tabs. Then place button

```
<p-tabView class="info-audit-tabview col-md-4">
  <div class="ui-tabview-panels">
    <p-tabPanel header="UnSelected List">
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Selected List" ng-reflect-header="Audit Trail">
    </p-tabPanel>
  </div>
</p-tabView>
<button type="button" pButton label="Export"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation on the tabView page, the `TabPanel` have a specific `headerStyleClass` that you use like this

```
<p-tabPanel header="Header 1" headerStyleClass="myCustomClass"></p-tabPanel>
```

What you can do is give it a class of your own, and style it. Basically, you're creating a tab that looks like a button.

If it's not what you want, please tell me so that I can find another solution for you.

Comment: i'll try this solution, any clue what the css we need to make tab look like a button?

Comment: Well that depends on the button you want ! I'm not your user or your customer, so I can't tell you, but if you have no idea, just find a button you like and copy its CSS to paste it in your custom class, this should widely do the trick. Oh and if your style doesn't apply, try using the `!important` keyword, I remember having issues with primeNG and custom CSS