# Primeng TabView add content after tabs

Tags: html, angular, primeng, tabview

I need to have 2/3 tabs, but in the end and on the same line, I need to add buttons, custom component etc etc ...

I didn't found a way to do it, and there is no responses when googling :-o

```html
    <p-tabView>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header 1">
            Content 1
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header 2">
            Content 2
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header 3">
            Content 3
        </p-tabPanel>
        <!-- here start my custom html - without tabs content -->
        <p-tabPanel>
            <button></button>
            <app-my-custom-component></app-my-custom-component>
        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
```

Here an example of what I need.
On the same line, I want to add custom html, and when I click on it, there is no tab, but other actions ... like dialog for example

[image]

Comment: Please look ah this question, I think is the same that you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886820/angular-2-primeng-add-button-next-to-tabs

Comment: Yes, I already saw this post, but it didn't content a valid answer.
It didn't help me :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<p-tabView> 

  <p-tabPanel header="Header 1"> Content 1 </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Header 2"> Content 2 </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Header 3"> Content 3 </p-tabPanel>

  <!-- here start my custom html - without tabs content -->
  <p-tabPanel>
     <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <p-button icon="pi pi-chevron-up" (click)="openPrev()">
        </p-button>
     </ng-template>
  </p-tabPanel>

  <p-tabPanel>
     <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <app-my-custom-component></app-my-custom-component>
     </ng-template>
  </p-tabPanel> 
  
</p-tabView>
```

Comment: Indeed, it works, but the problem, it select the tab and open the empty content ...
There is a way to prevent the tab to be selected ? (by allowing the click on that tab)

Comment: I'm sorry. I've tried re-doing it with programmatic control and with the [disabled] attibut in <p-tabPanel>, but I didn't achieved any successful results. I hope someone helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69558747/21021802).

To prevent the content from opening and only trigger the button action, try this:

- Add $event.stopPropagation() to the button (click) method:

```html
<button pButton type="button" label="Action button"
  (click)="performRequiredAction();$event.stopPropagation();" >
</button>
```

- Using CSS, disable clicking on the parent element, which is the tab, and enable it for the child button:

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
    .p-tabview-nav-link:has(button){
        pointer-events: none;
        button {
            pointer-events: all;
        }
        
        /* Additional styling for a better button look */
        border: none !important;
        padding: 0 4px !important;
        height: 100%;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```